# How to add metadata through grpc ruby client?

Tags: ruby, metadata, grpc

How to add metadata through grpc ruby client? example code snippet will help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show us your initial attempts regarding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metadata is an optional parameter to any method call. For example:

```
metadata = { 'key' : 'value' }
response = service.method(argument, metadata: metadata)
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. The `metadata` key suggested by other responses did. Perhaps the API has changed since this was posted?

Comment: Yes. You will get the error TypeError: hash key "key" is not a Symbol.
Keyword argument metadata must be used instead given
response = service.method(argument, metadata: metadata)

Answer (score 4):

do it this way

```
response = stub.rpc_call(req, {metadata: {key1: value1, key2: value2}})
```

you can find the right usage by reading grpc rspec code

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass metadata as a hash with key `metadata`.

On the server side, assuming you have `your_method(your_req, _call)`, the metadata will be available as `_call.metadata`.